# Can not find Imagemagick files

Tags: debian, imagemagick

I want to modify Imagemagick policy.xml file but can not find any Imagemagick files on my server. I checked /var/lib and other folders, but nothing.

I am running Debian system and installed Imagemagick using `apt-get install imagemagick`.

```
serv5:/usr/bin# which imagemagick
serv5:/usr/bin# whereis imagemagick
imagemagick:
serv5:/usr/bin#
serv5:/usr/bin# apt-get install imagemagick
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
imagemagick is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
serv5:/usr/bin#
serv5:/usr/bin# which convert
/usr/bin/convert
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
# dpkg -L imagemagick
```

Answer (score 0):

It's delivered by `imagemagick-common` under Debian.

```
$ dpkg -L imagemagick-common | grep xml
/etc/ImageMagick/coder.xml
/etc/ImageMagick/colors.xml
/etc/ImageMagick/log.xml
/etc/ImageMagick/magic.xml
/etc/ImageMagick/mime.xml
/etc/ImageMagick/policy.xml
/etc/ImageMagick/quantization-table.xml
/etc/ImageMagick/thresholds.xml
/etc/ImageMagick/type.xml
/etc/ImageMagick/type-dejavu.xml
/etc/ImageMagick/type-ghostscript.xml
/etc/ImageMagick/type-windows.xml
/etc/ImageMagick/delegates.xml
```